# How to select IDs from second table which all IDs exists in first table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have following tables:

**TravelPage**

```
TravelPageID     TravelIDRef     PassengerIDRef
    1                1                10
    2                1                15
    3                2                10
```

**Temp**

```
PassengerID
   10
   15
```

I want to get all `travelIDRefs` from `TravelPage` Table which all `PassegerIDs(10,15)` from `temp table` exists in `travelPage table`

**Result should be**

`travelIDRef=1`  because both 10,15 exists just for `TravelIDRef=1`

```
declare @TravelPage table
(
   TravelPageID int,
   TravelIdRef int,
   PassengerIDRef int
)
declare @temp table
(
   PassengerID int
)


insert into @TravelPage
  values(1,1,10),(2,1,15),(3,2,10)

insert into @temp
values(10),(15)
```

Comment: do ain inner join

Answer (score 1):

Use the `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT t.TravelIdRef
FROM TravelPage t
CROSS JOIN Temp p
GROUP BY TravelIdRef
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.PassengerIDRef) = COUNT(DISTINCT p.PassengerID)
```

Or with a sub query instead of a join :

```
SELECT t.TravelIdRef
FROM TravelPage t
GROUP BY TravelIdRef
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.PassengerIDRef) = 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.PassengerID) FROM Temp p)
```